# How can I optimize and manage disk space in offline installation of Visual Studio 2022 safely? Is a 160GB size normal?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have been utilizing Visual Studio 2022 Community for coding and app development, encompassing frameworks from .NET 4.8 to Core 8.0. I opted for an offline installation method, using the command
`vs_community.exe --layout D:\VS\VS_2022_Community\LocalVSCache --lang en-US` since August 2022.

Periodically, I run the same command to download updates in the same directory. However, the folder size has now grown to 160GB. While I understand that updates contribute to this, I'm concerned that there might be temporary files or folders that are no longer needed.

My primary questions are:

1. Is a 160GB size normal for an offline installation of Visual Studio 2022?
2. Are there potentially obsolete temporary files or folders that I can safely remove to reduce the folder size?
3. How can I optimize the folder without jeopardizing any working packages or essential installation files?

Note: I'm still building winforms, webforms and asp.net core apps.

I appreciate any insights or recommendations to manage the disk space efficiently and maintain a streamlined Visual Studio environment.

[Visual Studio Community 2022 size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGC7L.png)

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but recently, the Visual Studio installer introduced a cleanup option in its update settings, maybe that helps?